# Angular 6: How to render inject data in separate section based on mat-nav-list selected item?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of items which I would like to use as a type of selector wherein the item is clicked and the resulting data is rendered in a div below it.

My mat-nav-list is as follows:

```
<mat-nav-list>
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let group of groups">
      <h4 mat-line>{{group.imageUrl}}{{group.name}}</h4>
   </mat-list-item>
```

I want to inject the data from the selected group into a div further down the page.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a property on the class, set it on the list item click, and then use the same property to bind to the div that you want to display the data on.

```
  <h4 mat-line (click)="setData(group)">{{group.imageUrl}}{{group.name}}</h4>
```

In TS:

```
setData(group) {
  this.selectedGroup = group;
}
```

In the DIV that is further down the page:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedGroup">
  {{ selectedGroup | json }}
  <!--You can do whatever you want with selectedGroup here-->
</div>
```

Here's a Sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Just ignore the table above. Everything is inside the AppComponent.